# jQuery AJAX catch status code errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to catch specific response errors using jQuery's $.ajax.

When there is an 500 or 404 error code, instead of running the status code functions, it runs the error function and I get an alert box instead of what is supposed to happen

Here is what my code looks like

```
// get page data
getPageData: function(url, callback) {

    url = ajaxLoader.getURL(url);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        data: {_ajax_loader: 1},
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            alert('There was a problem loading that page. You may need to refresh.');
        },
        statusCode: {
                404: function(response) {
                    ajaxLoader.fetchPage('/missing');
                },
                500: function(response) {
                    ajaxLoader.fetchPage('/error'); 
                }
            }           
    }).done(callback);
},
```

Answer (score 9):

This is by design. `error` is executed when an error is returned by the server. Further, the functions defined in `statusCode` are also [called](https://jsfiddle.net/p1947xjj/) as well. The same applies to `complete` and `success` handlers.

You could modify your error handler not to run when the error code is already defined in `statusCode`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo',
    type: 'get',
    success: function() {
        console.log('ajax.success');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status) {
        // check if xhr.status is defined in $.ajax.statusCode
        // if true, return false to stop this function
        if (typeof this.statusCode[xhr.status] != 'undefined') {
            return false;
        }
        // else continue
        console.log('ajax.error');
    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function(response) {
            console.log('ajax.statusCode: 404');
        },
        500: function(response) {
            console.log('ajax.statusCode: 500');
        }
    }
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p1947xjj/1/)

Comment: What kinds of things can cause the server to return an error that are not handled by HTTP error codes?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using the error callback in addition to the statusCode object. The error callback is triggered when any type of error occurs, including HTTP errors like 404 or 500.

To fix this, you need to remove the error callback and only use the statusCode object.

Here is the corrected code:

// get page data
getPageData: function(url, callback) {

```
url = ajaxLoader.getURL(url);

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    data: {_ajax_loader: 1},
    statusCode: {
            404: function(response) {
                ajaxLoader.fetchPage('/missing');
            },
            500: function(response) {
                ajaxLoader.fetchPage('/error'); 
            }
        }           
}).done(callback);
```

},

This way, only the appropriate function will be called when a 404 or 500 status code is returned, and not the error callback.

Answer (score -1):

$.ajax has `success` and `error` functions, so you can handle it with `jqXHR` defined for both.

On success:

```
success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
        switch(jqXHR.status){
           case 200:
                    //status ok
                    break;
           case 206:
                    //Partial Content
                    //awesome code for handle it
                    break;

        }
    }
```

On error:

```
error: function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
        switch(jqXHR.status){
           case 400:
                    //Bad Request
                    //awesome code for handle it
                    break;
           case 404:
                    //Not Found
                    //awesome code for handle it
                    break;

        }
    }
```

Here all [status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score -2):

It will execute both the `error` and appropriate `StatusCode` function.

The only issue with your code is that in your StatusCode functions, you have the argument of `response` (which I assume is the argument for the success function), when it should match the error function arguments, as follows:

```
// get page data
getPageData: function(url, callback) {

    url = ajaxLoader.getURL(url);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        data: {_ajax_loader: 1},
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            alert('There was a problem loading that page. You may need to refresh.');
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function(xhr, status) {
                ajaxLoader.fetchPage('/missing');
            },
            500: function(xhr, status) {
                ajaxLoader.fetchPage('/error'); 
            }
        }           
    }).done(callback);
},
```

With this, if a 404 or 500 is received, both the `error` function and the `404/500` function will execute. If you instead desire to have only the `404/500` function execute, and the `error` function will only execute if the returned status is not 404 or 500, you can do this as follows:

```
// get page data
getPageData: function(url, callback) {

    url = ajaxLoader.getURL(url);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        data: {_ajax_loader: 1},
        error: function(jqXHR, status) {
            switch (jqXHR.status) {
                case 404:
                    ajaxLoader.fetchPage('/missing');
                    break;
                case 500:
                    ajaxLoader.fetchPage('/error');
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('There was a problem loading that page. You may need to refresh.');
            }
        }         
    }).done(callback);
},
```

Comment: Since the `statusCode` functions don't use their arguments, what difference does it make what arguments he lists?

Comment: It doesn't really make a difference, just outlining that to show that the error arguments are expected, instead of the success arguments.

Comment: You said "Your issue here is...", which implies that it's the reason it's not working as intended.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Edited.